# Web application that prompts credentials off network and uses Windows credentials on the network

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, active-directory, iis-7.5

I am implementing a C# MVC 4 application hosted in IIS 7.5 to replace the company intranet. The requirement is that when a user is at their personal workstation logged in with their windows credentials they will not be prompted to login(this is not optional the customer is firm on this as they believe this is how SharePoint works. Though I cannot confirm), however when they are on a mobile device or on a personal computer off the local network they will be promoted for their credentials. Also, while off the network the user should be able to log out, and the application should log out automatically after a period of inactivity. All users who have access to the application will have AD credentials.

I attempted to get a working solution with windows authentication, but it is my understanding that windows authentication is not intended for use outside a local network. Even if I could get the desired authentication results with this option there is no ability to log out without a significant amount of kludge and hacking with JS.

It appears that by default forms authentication is the answer, but is there a way to utilize the users windows credentials and authenticate against active directory with those without prompting the user to login while on the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately even after I called Microsoft I was unable to find a good work around for this issue. They did suggest Active Directory Federation Service. This was not an option for us.

There is also a great [blog post](http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/) that does the opposite of what I am looking for but could probably be manipulated to work.

After working with my product owner we settled on a true forms authentication model. The way I was able to appease them was for users on the local network I am setting the time out for the forms authentication token and cookie to a longer duration and refreshing the duration so that if users are active on the application often enough they may never be prompted to log in.

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it has allowed us to meet the requirements set by the product owner. If anyone has additional suggestions I would love to hear them.